# Modify custom option product detail page

Tags: opencart, opencart-module

we need product custom option based on  length and price. we need same requirement of product option according following site :-

"https://www.petflow.com/product/taste-of-the-wild/taste-of-the-wild-high-prairie-dry-dog-food"

please let us know how can do it in opencart 
Thanks

Comment: You have to custom work on in opencart

Comment: Please let us know how can do it custom